# Woocommerce registration required on Checkout if product category in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have set up woocommerce to require registration for checkout on Woocommerce settings. My website sells courses and for that reason I require registration.

However, I want to start selling physical items too, and would like to disable registration required if cart only has non-virtual products.

I have this on my theme's **form-checkout.php** :

```
foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {

// Check if there are non-virtual products 

if (! $cart_item['data']->is_virtual()){
    
  /* HERE SHOULD COME THE CODE TO ENABLE REGISTRATION REQUIRED */ 
  
  break;
}
```

I'm a bit confused on how to proceed, as I don't know if this is something that woocommerce would allow.

Any ideas how this could be achieved?

thanks!

Comment: Check the second post on this page: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/force-login-before-checkout-only-for-digital-products/ You deny guest checkout globally and then you can enable it per product. And this is the detailed explanation on Github https://gist.github.com/contemplate/2adc7be2c72d585a07ac6f90b1f1e1b4#gistcomment-2660293 I hope this can help.

Comment: No need to edit template files, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66172825/11987538) which is very related to your question

Comment: thanks both, this last one worked like charm!